# > /dev/zero cancel the previous append

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am working on an program related to shell commands.

I want to make that, when the user enter an command, this not show any output.

I have tried adding `> /dev/null` to the command, this works well for commands like

```
$ echo "some text" | sudo tee some.txt  > /dev/zero

$ cat some.txt
some text
```

But if the user enter a command with append (>>), the new line is not added as expected

```
$ echo "appending another line" >> some.txt > /dev/zero

$ cat some.txt
some text
```

I understood that the commands were executed from left to right, something escapes me

Comment: A program only has one set of file descriptors when it starts up. So when `sudo tee` is invoked, its stdout can go to one place. It can go to `some.txt`, **or** it can go to `/dev/zero`, but it's strictly one or the other. While you're doing two redirections, and they are indeed left-to-right, but only the last of those redirections (the rightmost one!) is the one that's still in place when `sudo` is executed.

Comment: BTW, note that "left to right" is _processing order_, not necessarily execution. All parts of a pipeline run in parallel to each other, and there's no guarantee of startup order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the user enter a command with append (>>), the new line is not added as expected

The redirections, *are* executed left to right. `>>some.txt` redirects stdout to `some.txt`, then `>/dev/null` *overwrites* that redirection and redirects stdout to `/dev/null`. Then the command is executed and the output of `echo` command is redirected to `/dev/null`.